# removing input highlight border on focus

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to remove the highlight from an input

.html:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-input value="" type="text" placeholder="Add a comment..."></ion-input>
  <button ion-button clear item-right (click)="send()">POST</button>
</ion-item>
```

[image]

I also added this in .scss:

```
$text-input-md-show-success-highlight:  false;
$text-input-md-show-error-highlight:  false;
```

however, it doesn't take effect unless if I remove `ion-item` but then I cannot align the button `POST`

```
<ion-input value="" type="text" placeholder="Add a comment..."></ion-input>
  <button ion-button clear item-right (click)="send()">POST</button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok , the only solution i found... but this is not the best workaround

```
.item-md.item-input.input-has-focus .item-inner {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The SCSS variable is `$text-input-md-show-focus-highlight`.

Try:

```
$text-input-md-show-focus-highlight: false;
```

Docs [link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/)

Answer (score 0):

propably problem is in place where you defined your scss (and propably you defined it in your current @component styleUrls ?). if you generated your project with angular-cli define

```
$text-input-md-show-success-highlight:  false;
$text-input-md-show-error-highlight:  false;
```

in your style.scss in main directory and everythig should work fine

Comment: doesn't that apply it on App level ! I only want it in a specific page

Answer (score -1):

If you inspect that, you will get to know that the css affecting it is:

```
.item-input.input-has-focus::after{
  border-bottom-color: #387ef5;
}
```

So try,

```
.item-input.input-has-focus::after{
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

It should work.

**NOTE**: Put this in the correct css class hierarchy though.

Comment: none of them worked... after inspecting.. when i click on the input, this appears in styles `.input-has-focux .input-cover { display: none }` when I uncheck `display` the border highlight disappears..

Comment: First, if you click while inspecting anywhere, it is gonna disappear. So, that's not what it is. Second, I asked you to put this at a correct hierarchy. What is your html and css for this tried out solution?

Comment: maybe thats what im doing wrong.. Its inside the selector
`page-post { Your code }` 
besides, my `ion-item` is inside `ion-footer` in the html

Comment: Ok. Just put it correctly inside the style of `.item` in that css and try. May be it will work.